# Is it possible for nohup to write the output both to the file nohup.out AND to the screen/terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, nohup

I am using the `bash` shell.  I frequently use `nohup` to ensure that my processes are not stopped when I close the shell/terminal that started them.  I use a syntax like:

```
nohup myprocess
```

When starting, `nohup` gives the message:

> `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'`

Then, `nohup` gives no more output to the screen; it is all written to `nohup.out`.

Frequently, however, I would like to monitor the progress of my computation.  I can do this by reading `nohup.out` using `vi` or `tail`, but this can be time consuming to do a lot, especially when my computations take several hours.

Is there any way that I can print the output to ***both*** `nohup.out` (in case I lose internet connection and thus the terminal that started the process is closed) ***and*** to the screen?   Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you considered using `screen` or `tmux` instead of nohup?

Comment: @derobert Thanks. I have `screen` on my system, but I have never used it.  I don't have `tmux` on my system, but I can try to get it.

Comment: Just launch `screen`/`tmux` between logging in and starting `myprocess`.  Then detach from it with `prefix`,`d`.  `screen`'s prefix is `Ctrl-A`, while `tmux`'s prefix is `Ctrl-B`.  You can log out but as long as the machine stays up, your `screen`/`tmux` session will too.  Next time you log in, you can reattach the `screen`/`tmux` shell, via `screen -r` or `tmux attach`.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/414341/redirect-nohup-to-stdout

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can run

```
nohup yourprocess & tail -f nohup.out
```

Comment: tail -f is cool, unfortunately mine fails to display control characters properly

Comment: If you would like to change the nohup.out to something else, say run.log, and then follow it, use nohup myprocess > run.log 2>&1 & tail -f run.log

Answer (score 21):

Proof.

```
nohup yourprocess 1>&2  | tee nohup.out &
```